# add new inputs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I add new multiple inputs with angularjs?

I tried but can't binds ng-repeat with input ng-model. I wish to add ng-repeat of selectedItems to `<div class="item-text-wrap">`but It doesn't work unless initialized it.

If I click add new product button new Product Select field and new price input field will be displayed as in picture.

[image]

here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WPOESUlzTGfkeKLUtVUY?p=preview).

here is my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

      <body ng-controller="mycontroller">
 <!-- <div class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in selectedItems"> -->
          <div class="item-text-wrap">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
              <span class="input-label">Product</span>
              <select  ng-model="item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" ng-change="toggleChange(item)" class="col col-100"><option style="display:none" value="">select an item</option></select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Price</span>
               <input type="number" ng-model="item.price" placeholder="Select an item" ng-disabled="!item" />
            </label>
          </div>
          {{selectedItems}}
      </body>

    </html>
```

here is my script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectedItems = [];
  $scope.items = [{'id':1,'name':'apple', 'price': 100},
  {'id':2,'name':'orange', 'price':75},
  {'id':3,'name':'lemon', 'price':50}]

  $scope.toggleChange = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item), 1);
    $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
  };

});
```

Comment: Correct Plunker link

Comment: Can you explain a bit more , what do you want to achieve

Comment: I wish to add items to selectedItems, means more than one item. but I can't bind selectedItems with items. Please check in plunker. I updated the link.

Comment: that means you want more than one item in the selected items array based on the select tag. Am i right? If so, while calling the `toggle change` function comment out the `splice` function line

Comment: I can't Alhuck, user need to be displayed next input fields. This is just demo. There are some more properties in item object, like input date, which might be different.

Comment: why dont you use two different arrays object one for selected item and one for added one

Comment: is this what you need ???? http://embed.plnkr.co/OpYjLEpX8kScqfIMN175/preview

Comment: Thank zan, that's what I am asking. I tried but I can't bind selectedItem, item and new array. I m just naive in front end dev, just two months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent many hours to complete add new inputs fields to as pictures. It enable multiple duplicate entry. **WORKING PERFECT** as I wish to. Love it lot. :-)

It might not be the best solutions but It complete the task, I intended to and hope to be useful for others.

And please suggest any better approach.

1. **COPY** items to selectedItems by `angular.copy()`.

`Push is just pointer, point to ordinary address. So it constrains integrity of selectedItems data`

(accept better suggestions and knowledges)

2. change selected attribute to your selecteditem of the record of selectedItems, when you choose options, for future purpose.
3. add new product or remove one, whatever you want to.
4. choose selected attribute only.

here is screenshot.

[image]

here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rafW0eXYG7eEfk40IZ1g?p=preview)

here is html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

  <body ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <div class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="items in selectedItems">
        <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice(items)">-</button>
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <span class="input-label">Product</span>
          <select  ng-model="item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" ng-change="toggleChange(item, items)"><option style="display:none" value="">select an item</option></select>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Price</span>
           <input type="number" ng-model="item.price" placeholder="Select an item" ng-disabled="!item" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="addItems()">Add new Product</button> <br>
      {{selectedItems}} <br><br>
      <button ng-click="displaySelectedOnly()" ng-disabled="bool == false">futurepurpose</button> <br>
      {{selectedItemsOnly}}
  </body>

</html>
```

here is js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectedItems = [];
  $scope.items = [{'id':1,'name':'apple', 'price': 100},
  {'id':2,'name':'orange', 'price':75},
  {'id':3,'name':'lemon', 'price':50}]
  $scope.selectedItemsOnly = [];
  $scope.bool = false;

  $scope.toggleChange = function (item, items) {
    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
      if(!angular.isUndefined(item.selected) && item.selected === true){
           item.selected = false;
      } 
    });
    item.selected = true;
    $scope.bool = true;
  };


  $scope.addItems = function (items){
    $scope.selectedItems.push(angular.copy($scope.items));
  }

  $scope.removeChoice = function (items){
    $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(items), 1)
    if($scope.selectedItem.length === 0) $scope.bool = false;
  }

  $scope.displaySelectedOnly = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function(items){
        angular.forEach(items, function(item){
          if(!angular.isUndefined(item.selected) && item.selected === true){
            $scope.selectedItemsOnly.push(item);
          } 
        });             
    });

  }

  $scope.addItems($scope.items);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add items to your `seletedItems` array from `items` array and avoid duplicates just use `indexof` to find if there's item in your selectedItems array already and if it found delete it, if not just add it!!!

As per your updated question, you can do this using directive,

Here i used one `directive` and `ngRepeat` to create Dom again and again using the directive while clicking add `new product function` by increasing the array count!!!

Here is the updated plunker with your code!!!!!

http://embed.plnkr.co/OpYjLEpX8kScqfIMN175/preview

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, dude. But I need addtional items' inputs field. Please see picture in question. I just added.

Comment: how many input fields and select fields you need to add like this and what are its options for `select` tag

Comment: 3 input fields need to add for a records. like inventory item input. input items, amount per packages, and arrived date. Number of records will be dynamic.

Comment: Thank, it's helpful but can't accept duplicate entry. Anyway, appreciate for your help. :-) I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

check out this plunker: as i dont know you full object details you can still add few condition to validate items.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Arw9Jibeu0kmLzgoX8ou?p=preview

```
  <button ng-click="addProduct(item)">add new product</button>
  <br />
    {{selectedItems}}
  <br />
  <b>Added items:</b>
  {{addedItems}}
```

let me know , if need any changes in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, dude. But I need addtional items' inputs field. Please see picture in question. I just added.